# Why are the 1st 2nd and 3rd normal forms ignored in some database books/courses?

Tags: database-theory, normal-forms

Why are the 1st 2nd and 3rd normal forms ignored in some Database books/courses?

specifically:

https://lagunita.stanford.edu/courses/Engineering/db/2014_1/about

and

[https://www.amazon.com/Database-Systems-Complete-Book-2nd/dp/0131873253/ref=sr_1_4?ie=UTF8&qid=1488557782&sr=8-4&keywords=database+systems](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0131873253)

only cover BCNF and 4thNF.

Why?

Comment: I don't think this is really answerable. How could we know why individual authors chose to include some material and not others?

Comment: I can only bet... BCNF sometimes called 3.5NF is stronger that 3NF. To have 3NF it must be in the 2NF and 1NF, so having 3.5NF would resolve former issues.

Comment: Are they unimportant in practice?

Comment: Right. They're used rarely enough that some texts simply omit any discussion of them except, perhaps, to mention that they exist.